# PhpStorm Terminal does not work

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

P.S.: Sorry me and please be lenient with my English.

Since I Updated my PhpStorm, internal terminal stop works.

My terminal is not work now, just a gray screen:

[image: terminal]

My OS:
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I'd installed:

[image: phpstormversion]
[image: phpstormversion]

I try to remove all my local settings, then reinstalled it without any imported settings, but nothing changed.

at idea.log I found that: [error](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M2Mesezc-m7lYl_Dkex-UVsDi8pCOP1CZHcghfeK-u4/edit?usp=sharing).

How to decide it?

Comment: For more information:

Also I had trouble with Behat Plugin, but if I right understand it, it does not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had been solved. I don't know about what was reason of it.

But I had been upgrade all installed tools at my system. Then I try again fully "reinstall" (remove&download&extract&init) PHPStorm with deleting personal settings and plugins. And finally now it's work.